# Get a difference in dates and aggregate results over a third column

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| ACCOUNT   | PAID_DATE  | DUE_DATE   |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| 103240005 | 2010-07-22 | 2009-11-30 |
| 103240005 | 2010-07-22 | 2007-09-30 |
| 103240005 | 2010-07-22 | 2008-09-30 |
| 103240006 | 2010-07-22 | 2009-09-30 |
| 103240006 | 2010-07-22 | 2007-07-22 |
| 103240007 | 2010-07-22 | 2008-07-22 |
| 103240008 | 2010-07-22 | 2009-08-31 |
| 103240009 | 2010-07-22 | 2007-12-31 |
| 103240009 | 2010-07-22 | 2008-12-31 |
| 103240005 | 2010-07-22 | 2009-12-31 |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

The above sample dataset is from a banking application I am building. 
I would like to get per account, the amount of records where the payments were made on time, i.e `DATEDIFF(DUE_DATE, PAID_DATE)  = 0`. Please note that there are multiple entries per account.

Here is my problematic query:

```
select ACCOUNT_NUMBER, count(DATEDIFF(PAID_DATE, DUE_DATE) as diff) as diff_count 
from TRANSACTIONS 
where diff=0 group by ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the paid_date and due_date are of date type, you can use:

```
select account_number, 
  sum(paid_date = due_date) as diff_count
from transactions
group by account_number;
```

if the two dates are equal, the result will be true which is taken as 1 by mysql and 0 for false.

#### EDIT:

You can further add more aggregates as needed. For e.g. - count where the overdue is 10 or more days, you can use:

```
select account_number, 
  sum(paid_date = due_date) as diff_count,
  sum(datediff(paid_date, due_date) >= 10) as overdue,
from transactions
group by account_number;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to extend this query to say, return all records where the 'overdue time' is 10 days, etc.

Comment: @dkay_ - You can add a similar condition for that scenario. Updated the answer.

Comment: It works great. The only edit required is the second 'variable name' for the second aggregator, e.g diff_count2. So your edited query would look like this:

select account_number, 
  sum(paid_date = due_date) as diff_count,
  sum(datediff(paid_date, due_date) >= 10) as diff_count2,
from transactions
group by account_number;